# Create accessible directories with mkdir or md Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, mkdir, winpe

I'm trying to run a batch script for our WinPE disk, and I want ImageX to back up to a user defined portable hard drive. However, ImageX will not save to a folder or location if it doesn't exist. So I'm running a check inside the batch file to see if the directory exist. If it doesn't, then it creates the directory. My problem is once the directory is created, and ImageX tries to write to it, it errors out and says "Access is denied."

Is there a way for me to create a directory that lets anyone read or write to it in Windows Command Prompt? The cmd prompt is already running as an Administrator within Windows PE.

Comment: mkdir creates directories that inherit file permissions. If you have the power to created it, running ImageX as the same user ought to be able to write to it. "Access Denied" doesn't always tell you what it was trying to do when it got error 5. Can you give us the output of the command? You could also try running procmon during the operation to see what filesystem attempt actually resulted in ACCESS_DENIED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create the directory you can try using the [icalcs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command to change the permissions.

You can give Full access a user by running this command:

```
icacls <Directory> /grant <User>:F
```